# Turn off screensaver while openmoko app is running

Tags: openmoko

In openmoko (stable hybrid release, SHR), how do you programatically turn-off the screensaver (the dimmed/blank screen after a few seconds of inactivity) just while your app is running?

Answer (score 1):

In X, you can run

```
xset s off
```

to turn off the screensaver. Similarly gnome/freedesktop exposes a DBUS API to control and inhibit screensaver mode. I don't know if OpenMoko supports the freedesktop spec, but if it does you should be able to use DBUS directly. You can see how Totem does it [here](http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/totem/trunk/lib//totem-scrsaver.c?view=markup).

Answer (score 1):

FSORaw is a wrapper that you can use externally to claim resources like the display. This will prevent screen blanking. But if it is your own application I would recommend claiming the same display resources within your software.

[more about fsoraw and resources](http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/FSO_Resources#Display)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that through the D-BUS API of [freesmartphone](http://freesmartphone.org/), it is also possible to prevent suspends.

```
mdbus -s org.freesmartphone.ousaged /org/freesmartphone/Usage org.freesmartphone.Usage.SetResourcePolicy CPU auto
mdbus -s org.freesmartphone.ousaged /org/freesmartphone/Usage org.freesmartphone.Usage.SetResourcePolicy Display auto
```

Replace auto with enabled or disabled.

‏You can find the documentation for this D-BUS method at http://git.freesmartphone.org/?p=specs.git;a=blob_plain;f=html/org.freesmartphone.Usage.html;hb=HEAD#GetResourcePolicy